# Fancybox not working as expected (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Tried recreating this error in a Fiddle, but no luck. Not sure where the error is.

I have a sample site working **[here](http://webfro.gs/south/tour3579/fancybox-index.html)**...

On my actual site, I have the same set up. See it **[here](http://webfro.gs/south/tour3579/index2.html)**... 
(scroll down to programs, and you'll see the word "Ajax" - Click on it)

You'll notice the first sample site works fine. But the second site is not working...

It's using the following to initiate Fancybox...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

    });
</script>
```

I'm lost here and I really want to use this, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: why are you two versions of jQuery ?

Comment: The bottom one is being called for something else after the page loads. I did just take it out though. Take a look again [**here**](http://webfro.gs/south/tour3579/index2.html) It's falling behind some other jquery objects...

Comment: It's not working. It falls behind other objects... I need to add a z-index now, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `z-index` you add this code in html `<head>` section it works well

```
<style>    
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        z-index: 99999 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Page jump to the top problem can actually be done with a helper in Fancybox 2.

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
  padding: 0,
  helpers: {
    overlay: {
      locked: false
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That worked, but when I click on the href, it scrolls back up to the top of the page. Any idea how to keep it in place, so the user doesn't have to scroll back down to where they were?

Comment: which href? inside fancy box or somewhere?

Comment: Now that it's working, I've placed the href where I wanted it. Go to the page [**here**](http://webfro.gs/south/tour3579/index2.html) and under Programs, click on the top, left column (picture of a police officer). That's the href I'm talking about. If you click on it, you'll notice it scrolls back to the top of the page. How do I avoid that?

Comment: check updated answer.if it helps accept as answer